# Responsive modal div scrolling on iphone

Tags: html, css, iphone, responsive-design

I have a pretty basic modal setup: A parent div that is fixed with dark background that scrolls if the child is too big. A child div that is centered with the message in it.

My problem is the parent does not scroll on iphone. Is there a way around this?

css:

```
#blackout {
  position:fixed;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  overflow-y:auto;
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
#modal {
  background-color:white;
  margin:50px;
}
```

html:

```
<div id="blackout">
  <div id="modal">
    Lots of text
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've just copied your code into a jsfiddle and tested it on my iphone and it fine for me. Do you have any other code that could be affecting it?

Comment: @SamWillis Really? I may have to investigate further...